Passing an object to a route with vue-router
Based on this from vue-routers site it seems as though you can pass an object as a prop. However, everytime I try to do this it seems to it fail saying invalid param
My route is defined as follows:
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('../layouts/DashboardLayout.vue'),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '/upload',
          name: 'Upload Review',
          component: () => import('../pages/CertificationUploadPage.vue'),
          props: { mode: 'manual'}
        },
      ],
    },
    // default redirect to home page
    { 
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', 
      redirect: '/error',
      meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      }
    },
    { path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', 
      redirect: '/login',
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: false,
     }
    }
  ]
})

I programmatically push a new page using this:
router.push({ name: 'Upload Review', params : {mode: 'email'} })

I am curious if I can also go one step further and pass a nested object with some additional data I want to get to the next page/component or would I have to use pinia for that?

So what do you provide? params or props after all?

I wanted to do props but the example I found online which uses props in the route they use params in the push(). So Can you actually pass a prop object? If so the router.push() does not seem to have a prop object in useRoute()

May be you must define the path to use it this way.
Something like that:
routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('../layouts/DashboardLayout.vue'),
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true,
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '/upload/:mode?',
          name: 'Upload Review',
          component: () => import('../pages/CertificationUploadPage.vue'),
          props: { mode: 'manual'}
        },
      ],
    },

Then in component CertificationUploadPage:
<template>
  <h2>{{ localMode }}</h2>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const { mode } = defineProps<{
  mode: string;
}>();

const route = useRoute();
const localMode = ref(route.params.mode || mode);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('Mounted Mode');
  console.log(mode);
});
</script>


Best wishes
